# Joomla 2.5- MyPHP Admin MySQL- "Special Characters" are not going away when posting to article

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, character

I am very new to this.  I have a Joomla website and want to do something simple.  Using FormMaker and Artetics ArtSQL, I want to have users enter information into a form, then have the information displayed in an article.

HOWEVER... When information is entered into a form, the information that is sent to the MySQL database isn't always correct.  For example, I see ***br*** instead of multiple choice answers.

When the information is displayed using ArtSQL, the funky letters show up also.  I CANNOT figure out how to get rid of these special characters.  Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Please contact the developer of the extension as it is their job to be supporting you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the extension, this could be achieved by putting the test variable through the strip_tags function in PHP. You'd need to add something like this to the controller file before it gets inserted into your table:

```
<?php
echo strip_tags($text);
?>
```

It will remove the tags from the string, like the `<br>` tags, and other HTML elements.

If you're not sure what you're doing, it may be better contacting the third-party that created the extension, as has already been mentioned.